# Procedure foreign key sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I can't understand why the execution of this procedure doesn't work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Pro1
( 
    @factura_id int, @produs_id int, @pret float, @cantitate int,@nr_ordine int
)
as
begin
    if((select COUNT (id_produs) from Produse where id_produs=@produs_id)=1)
        update FacturaProdus set 
          id_factura=@factura_id,  
          id_produs=@produs_id,
          pret =@pret,
          cantitate = CONCAT ('-',convert(int,@cantitate)), 
          nr_ordine=@nr_ordine
    --where id_produs=@produs_id
else

    insert into FacturaProdus(id_factura,id_produs,pret,cantitate,nr_ordine) 
    values(@factura_id,@produs_id,@pret, @cantitate,@nr_ordine)

end
go
```

If the id_produs is different from the arg @produs_id then to put in table FacturaProdus the respective values.For example for:

```
exec Pro1 1,1,1,12,2
```

it updates in the table FacturaProdus the negative value of the cantitate and all the values given by arguments.Good.But for:

```
exec Pro1 1,2,1,12,2
```

it gives my the error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_fac2". The conflict occurred in database "VanzariP1", table "dbo.Produse", column 'id_produs'.

Why? Why it can't just put in the table that values from the exec arg?
Any advice?

Comment: Well we don't know what your table structures are like so how could we know? That is an indication that you are trying to insert a value that doesn't exist in the referenced table. Also your update in your procedure is problematic. It will update the entire table every time it executes. Looks like you have a where clause but it is commented out.

Comment: It updates me only if the product id exists.

Comment: Huh?? Your update has no where clause, that means every row will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, error text is pretty self-explanatory: you have foreign key constraint on `FacturaProdus` table which forces `FacturaProdus.id_produs` column to be reference to values from `Produse.id_produs` column.

So if you're trying to call your stored procedure with `@produs_id` which is absent in `Produse` table - you have to insert record having this id and some data into `Produse` prior to `insert into FacturaProdus` statement of your stored procedure.

Also notice this commented out part of statement `--where id_produs=@produs_id` is very dangerous, since you will update whole `FacturaProdus` table using values provided to the stored procedure.

I really doubt such an update was your intent.